# Finding the longest ordered list within an unordered list

Tags: sql, oracle

I am rephrasing my previous question as suggested by a commenter.

The below set represents the sales of a product in consecutive weeks.

```
22,19,20,23,16,14,15,15,18,21,24,10,17
```

I need to find the longest run of higher sales figures in consecutive weeks, i.e week-6 to week-11 represented by `14,15,15,18,21,24`.

I have got a query that returns the result, but would like to know the ways to improve it. Can anyone suggest some ways to do that please? Thanks in advance.

```
with 
raw_data (sales) as
(
  select '22,19,20,23,16,14,15,15,18,21,24,10,17' from dual
)
,
derived_tbl(week, sales) as
(
  select level, regexp_substr(sales, '([[:digit:]]+)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
  from raw_data connect by level <= regexp_count(sales,',')+1
)
,
coll(week, sales, salesdlag, salesdlead) as
(
  select week, sales, 
   nvl(sales - (lag(sales) over (order by week)), 0), 
   nvl((lead(sales) over (order by week) - sales), 0)
  from derived_tbl
)
,
filt_coll(week, sales, salesdlag, salesdlead) as
(
  select week, sales, salesdlag, salesdlead 
  from coll 
  where not (salesdlag < 0 and salesdlead < 0)
)
,
cte(startweek, sales, salesdlag, salesdlead, actualweek) as
(
  select week, sales, salesdlag, salesdlead, week from filt_coll 
  union all
  select cte.startweek, cl.sales, cl.salesdlag, cl.salesdlead, cl.week 
  from filt_coll cl, cte
  where cl.week = cte.actualweek + 1 and cl.sales >= cte.sales
)
,
pen_coll as
(
  select * from cte order by startweek,actualweek
)
,
final_coll as
(
  select startweek, actualweek, sales, count(startweek) over(PARTITION BY startweek) as cnt from pen_coll 
)
select LISTAGG(sales, ',') within group (order by null) as rslt 
from final_coll 
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from final_coll)
;
```

Comment: Why are you storing it as a comma delimited string and not in a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS005)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a collection (rather than a delimited string) to store the values and you can also use a hierarchical query to find the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT TRIM( LEADING ',' FROM SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( value, ',' ) ) AS week_values,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS first_week,
         id AS last_week,
         LEVEL AS num_weeks,
         MAX( LEVEL ) OVER () AS max_weeks
  FROM   (
    SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS value,
           ROWNUM As id
    FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 22,19,20,23,16,14,15,15,18,21,24,10,17 ) )
  )
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id + 1 = id AND PRIOR value <= value
)
WHERE  num_weeks = max_weeks
```

**Output**:

```
WEEK_VALUES       FIRST_WEEK LAST_WEEK NUM_WEEKS MAX_WEEKS
----------------- ---------- --------- --------- ---------
14,15,15,18,21,24          6        11         6         6
```

You could further restrict the hierarchical query to only start when the previous value is greater:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT TRIM( LEADING ',' FROM SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( value, ',' ) ) AS week_values,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS first_week,
         id AS last_week,
         LEVEL AS num_weeks,
         MAX( LEVEL ) OVER () AS max_weeks
  FROM   (
    SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS value,
           LAG( COLUMN_VALUE ) OVER ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS prev_value,
           ROWNUM As id
    FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 22,19,20,23,16,14,15,15,18,21,24,10,17 ) )
  )
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  START WITH prev_value IS NULL OR prev_value > value
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id + 1 = id AND PRIOR value <= value
)
WHERE  num_weeks = max_weeks
```

**Update**

Oracle Setup:

```
create table tst(id, value) as
  select rownum, round(dbms_random.value*9)
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 10000;
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT TRIM( LEADING ',' FROM SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( value, ',' ) ) AS week_values,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS first_week,
         id AS last_week,
         LEVEL AS num_weeks,
         MAX( LEVEL ) OVER () AS max_weeks
  FROM   (
    SELECT value,
           LAG( value ) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS prev_value,
           id
    FROM   tst
  )
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  START WITH prev_value IS NULL OR prev_value > value
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id + 1 = id AND PRIOR value <= value
)
WHERE  num_weeks = max_weeks
```

Comment: I am just beginning to learn beyond the basic select statements. Didn't know anything about collections. You have given me number of pointers to learn. thanks a lot.

Comment: tried replacing the collection with a result set from  `create table tst(id, value) as (select rownum, round(dbms_random.value*9) from dual connect by level <= 10000);` table. Does not seem to like it...

Comment: @Slkrasnodar Added an update that I hope would work (unable to test at the moment though).

Comment: thanks. tested it. compared to the CTE query, it seems to perform slower. evident when the rows in the `tst` table increase. tested with 100,000 rows.